# Jackrabbit JCR_SQL2: filter on a path of which only part is known

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr-sql2

I need to filter out some files that are in some folder that I don't know the full path of in advance, so I can't use ISDESCENDANTNODE. ¿Is there any other way? ¿Why path can't be cast to string so it can be used in a constraint with LIKE? I have see in another implementations that there is a function PATH but it's not part of the standard and it's not implemented in Jackrabbit.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The standard does not require this, as implementations may not be able (or willing to) index the path.

What exactly do you mean by "I don't know the full path of in advance"?

Comment: What I mean is that I only know one pattern of the path of the files that I want to filter. For example, I know that in the path there will be a directory with a certain name: '%/known-directory/%', but I don't know the initial part of the path because the directory can be anywhere in the hierarchy. Thank you!